# Get Pixel Values from Android Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, save

I'm currently writing an Android game using surfaceView. I've optimized the game as much as possible and it runs quite smoothly. However, I have collision detection incorporated which is a bit messy. I would like to do collision detection by reading pixels directly from the canvas. Is this possible to do? The closest to this that I have found was to attach a new bitmap to the canvas using setBitmap. Then when I drew to the canvas, the bitmap would be updated. Would this be the way to go? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although you should manage the collision detection in a different way, you can get the pixel color on a given position with the next line of code:

```
mView.mBitmap.getPixel(j, i)
```

mView is the View that contains your canvas and mBitmap is the Bitmap with which you created your canvas:

```
Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Canvas API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html):

> The Canvas class holds the "draw"
>   calls. To draw something, you need 4
>   basic components: A Bitmap to hold the
>   pixels, a Canvas to host the draw
>   calls (writing into the bitmap), a
>   drawing primitive (e.g. Rect, Path,
>   text, Bitmap), and a paint (to
>   describe the colors and styles for the
>   drawing).

So you wouldn't ever ask a canvas for pixel data, because the canvas itself doesn't really "own" pixel data.  The canvas which you use to make draw calls is always attached to a bitmap (the one you're drawing on), so that bitmap is where you should get your pixel data from.

Collision detection is usually costly, but going to a bitmap-based process could make it even worse, depending on what you're trying to do.  Just a heads up.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Josh.  If precision is that important in your app, you may want to incorporate screen size/resolution data into some kind of physics engine.  Trying to build a physics engine based entirely on visual processing is probably unnecessarily costly.